# MAA Filler Template Font Style Problem

Tags: xetex

I'm writing something using the "filler template" of the Mathematical Association of America. But it does not work properly - I can not make texts italic or bold. Neither `\it`, nor `\textit` does work.

What can be the problem?

```
%MSC Primary: XXXXX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{maa-monthly}% https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/maa-monthly.sty



\raggedbottom
%\flushbottom
%\final

%\setcounter{annual}{XXXX}
%\setcounter{volume}{XXX}
%\setcounter{issue}{X}
%\setcounter{page}{XXX}

\allowdisplaybreaks

%\theoremstyle{theorem}
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}


\begin{document}
\begin{filler}
[white]

\noindent {\large \bf \textsf{A Consequence of the Pythagorean Theorem}}\\


\noindent The well known Pythagorean theorem $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ relates the lengths of the three sides of a right triangle. We present an exciting consequence of this result, namely, that if two of the three sides of a right triangle have lengths that are even integers, then the third side must be of even length as well. 

To see this, suppose that $a$ and $b$ are even; then $a = 2a'$, $b = 2b'$, where $a'$ and $b'$ are positive integers.  Hence
\[   c^2 = (2a')^2 + (2b')^2  = 4(a'^2 + b'^2).     \]
The result when the hypotenuse and one of the legs are of even length is proved similarly.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{Ing} Ingham, A. E. (1932). \textit{The Distribution of Prime Numbers}. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.
\end{thebibliography}


\rightline{---Submitted by Carl F.\ Gauss}


\bigskip
\footnoterule
\footnotesize{doi.org/10.XXXX/amer.math.monthly.122.XX.XXX}

\footnotesize{MSC: Primary 00X00, Secondary 11Y11; 22Z22}

\end{filler}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No problem here with your template, as I'm able to change font to both **bold** and *italic* - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXZCU.png).

Comment: @Werner I tried that in both texstudio and miktex, it did not work. what should i do, what can the problem be... :(

Comment: show your log file which should reveal any font issues but you should never have markup like `\noindent {\large \bf \textsf{A Consequence of the Pythagorean Theorem}}\\ ` in a document. Why are you not using a section heading? (`\bf` has not been defined by default in latex since 1993, and the `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph will give a warning, but even without that use of explicit font and size commands should be very rare.

Comment: also `\noindent` and `\rightline`  should not be used in latex documents

Comment: I deleted the texstudio and miktex tags as texstudio is completely unrelated that is just the editor that you used to write the file, and the font issue applies to texlive and other tex distributions not just miktex

Comment: Nothing here is from AMS; the package specifies `maa-monthly`.  I've made the appropriate changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not mention it in the text but I assume from your tagging you used xelatex.

The package you are using is very old and not set up for xelatex, if you try you get multiple warnings about fonts and the output is

[image]

If you use pdflatex then the output is

[image]

Note however that the markup used is very strange, `\bf`,`\noindent`, `\rightline` should not be used in latex, and `\\`  should never be used at the end of a paragraph, doing so produces the warning

```
 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 28--29
```

and bad output.

Comment: I cant use pdflatex in this document. it gives an error like this: Font OT1/phv/bx/n/12.5=phvb7t at 12.5pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. ...{A Consequence of the Pythagorean Theorem}

Comment: You are missing the psnfss metrics so must have a _very_ minimal tex distribution? in texlive that would be /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/helvetic/phvb7t.tfm  I assume it should be in a similar location in miktex.

Comment: thanks for your time, and sorry; I did not understand, what should I do?

Comment: I have just asked on chat for a miktex user to comment. You should be able to simply update the relevant miktex package but I do not know miktex so someone else will have to say exactly what options to use in the miktex console.

Comment: Actually I'm using texstudio. but I can use both

Comment: texstudio is only an editor not a texsystem. If you are using miktex you will have to install the helvetic package in the miktex console.

Comment: @AliDursun as I commented above texstudio is not related to this at all, it does not matter what editor you use to write the file, just which tex system you process it with,

Comment: oh it did work! thank you. I installed "Helvetica" through miktex console.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile this with XeLaTeX, then you should declare suitable fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{maa-monthly}% https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/maa-monthly.sty

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}


\raggedbottom
%\flushbottom
%\final

%\setcounter{annual}{XXXX}
%\setcounter{volume}{XXX}
%\setcounter{issue}{X}
%\setcounter{page}{XXX}

\allowdisplaybreaks

%\theoremstyle{theorem}
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}


\begin{document}
\begin{filler}
[white]

\noindent {\large \bfseries \textsf{A Consequence of the Pythagorean Theorem}}

\bigskip

\noindent The well known Pythagorean theorem $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ relates the lengths 
of the three sides of a right triangle. We present an exciting consequence of this 
result, namely, that if two of the three sides of a right triangle have lengths 
that are even integers, then the third side must be of even length as well. 

To see this, suppose that $a$ and $b$ are even; then $a = 2a'$, $b = 2b'$, where 
$a'$ and $b'$ are positive integers.  Hence
\[   c^2 = (2a')^2 + (2b')^2  = 4(a'^2 + b'^2).     \]
The result when the hypotenuse and one of the legs are of even length is proved similarly.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{Ing} Ingham, A. E. (1932). \textit{The Distribution of Prime Numbers}. 
Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.
\end{thebibliography}


\rightline{---Submitted by Carl F.\ Gauss}


\bigskip
\footnoterule
\footnotesize{doi.org/10.XXXX/amer.math.monthly.122.XX.XXX}

\footnotesize{MSC: Primary 00X00, Secondary 11Y11; 22Z22}

\end{filler}

\end{document}
```

If you don't have the fonts installed in the system, the declarations can be (with an up-to-date TeX Live or MiKTeX distribution)

```
\setmainfont{STIXTwoText}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\setsansfont{texgyreheros}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-regular,
  BoldFont=*-bold,
  ItalicFont=*-italic,
  BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
]
```

[image]